# User should only be able to select 1 item in a list only once

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, duplicates, row

I have a gridview where I'm allowing user to select items for billing. now my problem is that the user is able to select same item twice in only one bill.

screen for reference:

[image: bill1]

Here the user is able to select duplicate items in the list which is not good.

my ASPX Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvRowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting1" EmptyDataText="Data Not Available">
   <Columns>
     <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash" DeleteText="" HeaderText="Remove Items" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Sl. No." />
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Name" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
       <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpItemname" runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="form-control select2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GetItemDetails" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
       <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HSN Code" Visible="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txthsn" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Available Quantity" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtQttyAvailable" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtQtty" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" OnTextChanged="CalculateTotal" AutoPostBack="true" Enabled="true"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Price" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitPrice" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Discount" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
       <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtdisc" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.GST" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
       <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtsgst" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C.GST" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtcgst" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="I.GST" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtigst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Price" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
       <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalPrice" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
       <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Add" OnClick="AddItem" CausesValidation="False" />
       </FooterTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
```

My c# code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Mylogic();
        SetInitialRow();
        ce1.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60);
        ce1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        BindGrid();  
    }
}
private void SetInitialRow()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column5", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column6", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column7", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column8", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column9", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column10", typeof(string)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
    dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column4"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column5"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column6"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column7"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column8"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column9"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column10"] = string.Empty;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
    Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
}
protected void GetItemDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in Gridview1.Rows)
    {
        Control ctrl = row.FindControl("drpItemName") as DropDownList;
        if (ctrl != null)
        {
            DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)ctrl;
            if (ddl.ClientID == ddl1.ClientID)
            {
                TextBox QttyAvailable = row.FindControl("txtQttyAvailable") as TextBox;
                TextBox UnitPrice = row.FindControl("txtUnitPrice") as TextBox;
                TextBox HsnCode = row.FindControl("txthsn") as TextBox;
                TextBox Discount = row.FindControl("txtdisc") as TextBox;
                TextBox SGST = row.FindControl("txtsgst") as TextBox;
                TextBox CGST = row.FindControl("txtcgst") as TextBox;
                TextBox IGST = row.FindControl("txtigst") as TextBox;                    
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
                conn.Open();
                string str = "select * from Stock where itemname='" + ddl1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    UnitPrice.Text = reader["unitprice"].ToString();
                    QttyAvailable.Text = reader["qtty"].ToString();
                    HsnCode.Text = reader["hsn"].ToString();
                    Discount.Text = reader["disc"].ToString();
                    SGST.Text = reader["sgst"].ToString();
                    CGST.Text = reader["cgst"].ToString();
                    IGST.Text = reader["igst"].ToString();
                }
                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
protected void CalculateTotal(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in Gridview1.Rows)
    {
        TextBox lblQty = row.FindControl("txtQttyAvailable") as TextBox;
        TextBox lblReceiveQty = row.FindControl("txtQtty") as TextBox;            
        if (lblQty != null && lblReceiveQty != null)
        {
            int Qty = 0, ReceiveQty = 0;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblQty.Text))
            {
                Qty = int.Parse(lblQty.Text);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblReceiveQty.Text))
            {
                ReceiveQty = int.Parse(lblReceiveQty.Text);
            }
            if (ReceiveQty > Qty)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "swal", "swal('Required quantity can not ne greater than available stock!', 'Royal Riders, Vijayapura', 'warning');", true);
                lblReceiveQty.Text = "";
                lblReceiveQty.Focus();
            }
            else if (Qty >= ReceiveQty)
            {
                TextBox AQtty = row.FindControl("txtQttyAvailable") as TextBox;
                TextBox QttyReq = row.FindControl("txtQtty") as TextBox;
                TextBox UnitPrice = row.FindControl("txtUnitPrice") as TextBox;
                TextBox TotPrice = row.FindControl("txtTotalPrice") as TextBox;
                TextBox DiscountPrice = row.FindControl("txtdisc") as TextBox;
                DropDownList ItemName = row.FindControl("drpItemname") as DropDownList;
                Control ctrl = row.FindControl("txtQtty") as TextBox;
                if (ctrl != null)
                {
                    TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)ctrl;
                    if (txt.ClientID == txt1.ClientID)
                    {
                        decimal totamt = Convert.ToDecimal(QttyReq.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(UnitPrice.Text);
                        decimal discountrate = (totamt) - (totamt * Convert.ToDecimal(DiscountPrice.Text)) / 100;
                        TotPrice.Text = discountrate.ToString("#,0.00");
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }
    }        
}
public static decimal totalgst;
public static decimal totalnetamt;
public static Int32 InitialStock;
protected void gvRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList drpItemName = (e.Row.FindControl("drpItemName") as DropDownList);
        foreach (GridViewRow row2 in Gridview1.Rows)
        {
            TextBox txt = row2.FindControl("txtTotalPrice") as TextBox;
            txt.Text = "0";
        }
        drpItemName.DataSource = GetData("SELECT itemname FROM Stock where rem != '1'");
        drpItemName.DataTextField = "itemname";
        drpItemName.DataValueField = "itemname";
        drpItemName.DataBind();            
        drpItemName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));
    }
}
private DataSet GetData(string query)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
}
private void AddNewRowToGrid()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DropDownList box1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("drpItemName");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txthsn");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtQttyAvailable");
                TextBox box4 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtQtty");
                TextBox box5 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("txtUnitPrice");
                TextBox box6 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("txtdisc");
                TextBox box7 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("txtsgst");
                TextBox box8 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[8].FindControl("txtcgst");
                TextBox box9 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[9].FindControl("txtigst");
                TextBox box10 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[10].FindControl("txtTotalPrice");
                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column4"] = box4.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column5"] = box5.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column6"] = box6.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column7"] = box7.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column8"] = box8.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column9"] = box9.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column10"] = box10.Text;
                rowIndex++;
            }
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
            Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }
    SetPreviousData();
}
private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)

            {
                DropDownList box1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("drpItemName");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txthsn");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtQttyAvailable");
                TextBox box4 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtQtty");
                TextBox box5 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("txtUnitPrice");
                TextBox box6 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("txtdisc");
                TextBox box7 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("txtsgst");
                TextBox box8 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[8].FindControl("txtcgst");
                TextBox box9 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[9].FindControl("txtigst");
                TextBox box10 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[10].FindControl("txtTotalPrice");
                box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
                box4.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();
                box5.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column5"].ToString();
                box6.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column6"].ToString();
                box7.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column7"].ToString();
                box8.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column8"].ToString();
                box9.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column9"].ToString();
                box10.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column10"].ToString();
                rowIndex++;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(box10.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(box10.Text))
                {
                    box10.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column10"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    box10.Text = "0";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
protected void Confirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    decimal grandgst = 0;
    try
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow g12 in Gridview1.Rows)
        {
            Control ctrl2 = g12.FindControl("txtigst") as TextBox;
            if (ctrl2 != null)
            {
                TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)ctrl2;
                TextBox cgst = g12.FindControl("txtcgst") as TextBox;
                TextBox sgst = g12.FindControl("txtsgst") as TextBox;
                TextBox igst = g12.FindControl("txtigst") as TextBox;
                TextBox linegst = g12.FindControl("txtTotalPrice") as TextBox;
                TextBox totamt = g12.FindControl("txtTotalPrice") as TextBox;
                sum += decimal.Parse(((TextBox)(g12.Cells[10].FindControl("txtTotalPrice"))).Text);
                decimal fcgst = Convert.ToDecimal(totamt.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(cgst.Text) / 100;
                decimal fsgst = Convert.ToDecimal(totamt.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(sgst.Text) / 100;
                decimal figst = Convert.ToDecimal(totamt.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(igst.Text) / 100;
                decimal ftot = Convert.ToDecimal(totamt.Text);
                totalgst = fcgst + fsgst + figst;
                grandgst += totalgst;
                totalnetamt = grandgst + sum;
            }
        }
        lblGstTotal.Text = grandgst.ToString();
        lblGTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
        lblGrandTotal.Text = (sum + grandgst).ToString();
        foreach (GridViewRow g1 in Gridview1.Rows)
        {
            string ITEMNAME = (g1.FindControl("drpItemname") as DropDownList).Text;
            string HSN = (g1.FindControl("txthsn") as TextBox).Text;
            string QTY = (g1.FindControl("txtQtty") as TextBox).Text;
            string UP = (g1.FindControl("txtUnitPrice") as TextBox).Text;
            string DIS = (g1.FindControl("txtdisc") as TextBox).Text;
            string SGST = (g1.FindControl("txtsgst") as TextBox).Text;
            string CGST = (g1.FindControl("txtcgst") as TextBox).Text;
            string IGST = (g1.FindControl("txtigst") as TextBox).Text;
            string TOT = (g1.FindControl("txtTotalPrice") as TextBox).Text;
            string InsertQuery = "Insert into Sales(bno,cdate,ctime,name,mobileno,address,gstno,pan,description,hsn,qtty,rate,disc,sgst,cgst,igst,linetotal,netamt,totalgst,grsamt,status,rem) values(@bno,@cdate,@ctime, @name, @mobileno, @address, @gstno, @pan, @description, @hsn, @qtty, @rate, @disc, @sgst, @cgst,@igst,@linetotal,@netamt,@totalgst,@grsamt,'1','0')";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bno", Convert.ToInt64(lblBillNo.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cdate", txtBDate.Text.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ctime", systemtime.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtcname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobileno", txtcmobile.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtcaddress.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gstno", txtgst.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pan", txtcpan.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", ITEMNAME);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hsn", HSN);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qtty", QTY);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", Convert.ToDecimal(UP));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@disc", Convert.ToDecimal(DIS));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sgst", Convert.ToDecimal(SGST));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cgst", Convert.ToDecimal(CGST));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@igst", Convert.ToDecimal(IGST));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@linetotal", Convert.ToDecimal(TOT));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grsamt", (lblGTotal.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalgst", Convert.ToDecimal(lblGstTotal.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@netamt", Convert.ToDecimal(lblGrandTotal.Text));
                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if(i > 0)
                    {
                        DropDownList ItemName = g1.FindControl("drpItemname") as DropDownList;
                        TextBox ReqQtty = g1.FindControl("txtQtty") as TextBox;
                        using (SqlConnection DeductStockCon = new SqlConnection(constring))
                        {
                            string query = "update Stock set qtty=CAST(IsNULL(qtty, '0') as int) - '" + Convert.ToInt32(ReqQtty.Text) + "' where itemname='" + ItemName.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
                            DeductStockCon.Open();
                            using (SqlCommand DeductStockCmd = new SqlCommand(query, DeductStockCon))
                            {
                                int j = DeductStockCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                if (j > 0)
                                {
                                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "swal", "swal('Items inserted successfully!', 'Royal Riders, Vijayapura', 'success');", true);                                        
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        LoadReceipt();
        Clear();
        Mylogic();
        SetInitialRow();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
private void Clear()
{
    txtcname.Text = "";
    txtcmobile.Text = "";
    txtcaddress.Text = "";
    txtcpan.Text = "";
    txtgst.Text = "";
    drpMode.SelectedValue = "--Select Payment Mode--";
}
private void Mylogic()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(bno) + 1 as Billno FROM Sales", con))
            lblBillNo.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        con.Close();
    }
}
protected void AddItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
        decimal sum = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRow row1 in Gridview1.Rows)
        {
            TextBox val1 = row1.FindControl("txtTotalPrice") as TextBox;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(val1.Text))
            {
                sum += 0;
            }
            else
            {
                sum += decimal.Parse(((TextBox)(row1.Cells[10].FindControl("txtTotalPrice"))).Text);
            }
        }
        lblGTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblGTotal.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
protected void Gridview1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
    SetInitialRow();
    BindGrid();
}
protected void BindGrid()
{
    Gridview1.DataSource = ViewState["CurrentTable"] as DataTable;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
}
private void LoadReceipt()
{
    SqlConnection CN;
    string MyConnectionString = null;
    MyConnectionString = constring;
    CN = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
    CN.Open();
    string SQL = null;
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM Sales where bno=(select max(bno) as 'Billno' from Sales)";
    SqlDataAdapter myDA = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, CN);
    CN.Close();
    SalesDataset DS = new SalesDataset();
    myDA.Fill(DS, "Sales");
    ReportDocument myRPT = new ReportDocument();
    myRPT.Load(Server.MapPath("Reports/BillReciept.rpt"));
    myRPT.SetDataSource(DS);
    rptSales.ReportSource = myRPT;
    rptSales.SeparatePages = false;
}
protected void btnLastReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadReceipt();
}
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
    int rowID = gvRow.RowIndex;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            if (gvRow.RowIndex < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
            { 
                dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowID]);
                ResetRowID(dt);
            }
        } 
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt; 
        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    } 
    SetPreviousData();
}
private void ResetRowID(DataTable dt)
{
    int rowNumber = 1;
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            row[0] = rowNumber;
            rowNumber++;
        }
    }
}
protected void Gridview1_RowDeleting1(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
    dt.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
    Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
    SetPreviousData();
    if(Gridview1.Rows.Count <= 1)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "swal", "swal('This is the only item in the list!', 'Royal Riders, Vijayapura', 'success');", true);
        SetInitialRow();
    }
}
```

Comment: means you want when a user select a item in the list it should not be shown again in the next row or user gets the error saying 'you have already selected this item please increase the Qty'

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways

1. Handle the code in `GetItemDetails()` Event Method do a `foreach` and check if the name selected in the `drpItemname` dropdown eqauls with the name of any of the previous `drpItemname` dropdownlist of the gridview
2. In the Method `AddNewRowToGrid()` before binding data to `drpItemname` dropdown remove those values from the `list` which are already selected in the previous `drpItemname` dropdown and then bind it and add row [Note this will work ambiguos because if user changes the dropdownvalue of previous list then you will get problem ]

Are these ideas helpfull ?

Ex 1 -

```
protected void GetItemDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in Gridview1.Rows)
    {
        Control ctrl = row.FindControl("drpItemName") as DropDownList;
        if (ctrl != null)
        {
            DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)ctrl;
            if((ddl1.ClientId != ddl.ClientId) && (ddl1.SelectedIndex == ddl.SelectedIndex)){
                  return Response.Write("Error") //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is showing error for even the first time I select an item

Comment: `if (ctrl != null)
                    {
                        if (ddl.SelectedIndex == ddl.SelectedIndex)
                        {
                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "swal", "swal('Item already selected, you can increase the required quantity instead!', 'Royal Riders, Vijayapura', 'warning');", true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
}
}`

Comment: actually you are doing if(ddl.SelectedIndex == ddl.SelectedIndex) instead of if(ddl1.SelectedIndex == ddl.SelectedIndex) hope you get it now ?

Comment: I know but I've tried using both and the result is the same.

Comment: You have to put one more condition for skipping the same element. I've Edited my code and added one more condition to the if

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181739/discussion-between-amit-chauhan-and-prateek-jahagirdar).